# iptables rules for port 53 not taking effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, iptables

My ubuntu 14.04 LTS server is receiving lots of incoming traffic on port 53 from different ip addresses. I am not hosting any DNS service. So I decided to block port 53:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 53 -j DROP

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
```

After that I save the new rules:

```
invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
```

So the final result looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.7           tcp dpt:8080
```

However when I use nethogs to monitor the traffic I still see traffic on port 53. Any idea why the rules are not taking effect?

For your notice: I have docker 1.9.1 installed.

Nethogs output:

[image]

and the list is growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is primarily UDP on port 53.

But why are you blocking it in OUTPUT chain as well? Do you not want to resolve any domain name from this machine?

Comment: Do you mean that, e.g. when I do curl google.com while OUTPUT on port 53 is blocked my system wont be able to resolve the domain?

Comment: DNS is maily UDP based. When you do curl google.com, a recursive resolving request is sent to DNS server based upon your network settings. The resolver(sort of client) used UDP dport 53, and if that fails it uses TCP dport 53.
`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP` is blocking packet going out to your DNS server on port 53 for TCP protocol.

Comment: Thank you!) I tried lains suggestion, however I am still getting traffic on port 53, I have update my question with nethogs output. Do you have any other idea what might be wrong?

Comment: can you paste output for `tcpdump  -i {correct interface} 'port 53'`

Comment: Its actually very large, here is a part of it: http://pastebin.com/f1i0ecqp

Comment: All right, now use `tcpdump -i {correct interface} 'tcp and dst port 53'` and `tcpdump -i {correct interface} 'udp and src port 53'` to find out what protocol are the requests using.

Comment: The second command returns 0 packages, the first gives 12 of these: `Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal.31463 > a7-67.akam.net.domain: Flags [R], seq 2062003767, win 0, length 0`

Comment: My bad, they should be `'udp and dst port 53 and dst {your_ip}'` and `'tcp and dst port 53 and dst {your_ip}'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35110/discussion-between-artworkad-and-zul-k-irshad).

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
```

Generally DNS traffic is UDP with fallback to TCP. You need to DROP UDP to port 53 too.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --destination-port 53 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your advice but I have no luck. I have updated my question with some more details.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD Then your problem is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your nethogs output shows your IP in discussion with port 53 on other IPs (mostly belonging to akam.net). This is normal behavior if you are running a resolving DNS client. The list is growing because your iptables filter is incorrect and blocks dpt:53 also on the OUTPUT chain, which blocks your own resolver.